# With a stack size of 32, would -16(%ebp) and 16(%esp) reference the same four bytes?

Tags: assembly, x86, stack

With a stack size of 32, would `-16(%ebp)` and `16(%esp)` reference the same four bytes? Assume we only want to read or write four bytes at a time and `esp` is at address `0`.

From my reading it seems like offsets from `ebp` read/write from the higher address to the lower and offsets from `esp` go low to high. Therefore, my answer would be no they do not reference the same four bytes. `-16(%ebp)` would reference bytes `16` to `20` while `16(%esp)` would reference bytes `12` to `16`. Is this assumption correct or am I totally wrong here? If it is correct, why does this difference exist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If by "stack size of 32", you mean that `%esp + 32 == %ebp`, then `-16(%ebp)` and `16(%esp)` reference the same address, namely `%esp + 16`. Thus, they refer to the same byte, word or dword -- objects are always read starting at the computed address and moving towards higher addresses (even if the offset expression is negative). Thus, you'd be reading the bytes `%esp + 16` through `%esp + 19`.

Comment: Thank you for the response. If this is the case, then why does `4(%ebp)` read the bytes `%esp + 32` through `%esp +36`. This is the source of my confusion.

Comment: This probably indicates that `%esp + 32 != %ebp` - you may be failing to account for a `push` or `call` that modified the stack pointer.

Comment: Which of these assumptions is incorrect? The return address is stored in the four bytes above the base pointer. The return address for a stack frame can be read using `4(%ebp)`. If the return address can be read using `4(%ebp)` and objects are always read starting at the computed address and moving towards higher addresses as you say, this would mean the return address is at bytes `4` to `8` assuming `ebp` is at byte `0`.

Comment: And that's usually the case - most functions start with a `push ebp; mov ebp, esp` which pushes the stack down 4 more bytes before it is loaded into `ebp`.

Comment: So are those four bytes part of the caller's frame or the callee's? In other words, are those four bytes above or below `ebp`.

Comment: The saved `ebp` is usually at `ebp+0`, putting the saved `eip` at `ebp+4`.

Comment: There's something obvious I'm missing, I'll do some more research. Thank you very much you have been a big help!

Comment: I wrongly assumed the saved `ebp` had to be stored below the address pointed at by `ebp`. I was also mistaking the "return address" for the "old base pointer". I understand now thanks a ton.